# Invertible matrix and hyperplanes

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Prove that every hyperplane $H$ of $M_n(\mathbb{K})$ $n>1$ contains at least an invertible matrix.

I did some tries and I see that those notes may help.
A hyperplane is a kernel of a linear form and every linear form is given by :
$\varphi:\Bbb M_n(\Bbb K)\to\Bbb K$, $\varphi(M)=\operatorname{trace}(AM)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! To get more people to help with your question, it may be helpful to include what you have tried and what parts you are finding difficult.

Comment: What have you tied so far?

Comment: I think $n>1$ is required

Answer (score 1):

Let the hyperplane be
$$
\{M:\operatorname{tr}(AM)=k\},
$$
where $A$ is a nonzero square matrix and $k$ is a scalar. By using elementary row and column operations, rank decomposition, or Smith normal form, we can always express $A$ as a product $PDQ$, where $P$ and $Q$ are invertible and $D\ne0$ is a diagonal matrix. So, if you put $M=Q^{-1}CP^{-1}$, the problem reduces to solving $\operatorname{tr}(DC)=k$ for an invertible matrix $C$. Since $D$ is a diagonal matrix, it shouldn't be hard to construct a solution. You may need to consider the cases $k=0$ and $k\ne0$ separately.